# building an XSLT string (variable) in a foreach loop

Tags: html, xml, xslt, variables

The problem I'm facing seems simple, but being a novice in everything **XSL** - I'm yet to find a proper solution. What I want to do is build a string by concatenating the results of a **foreach** element loop, that I can later on use as a value for an attribute of a HTML element.

Given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Desired output: `CBS;RCA;Virgin records`

I need a valid portion of **XSLT** code that would perform this transformation in a way described above. I believe I need an **xsl-variable** that would hold the result of concatenating `<company>` and a separator character `;`. How can this be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't believe you can use XSL variables to concatenate, because once a variable value is set, [it can't be changed](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_variable.asp). Instead, I think you want something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            ;<xsl:value-of select="country"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Does that make sense to you?

Edit: Just realized I may have misread how you were intending to use the variable. The snippet I posted above can be wrapped in a variable element for later use, if that's what you meant:

```
<xsl:variable name="VariableName">
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                ;<xsl:value-of select="country"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: @electroglow, could you do me the kindness of accepting my answer, then? There should be a green outline of a checkmark next to my answer that you can click to indicate that this is what worked for you and solved the question. It's considered good StackOverflow ettiquette to "accept" the right answer to each question you ask. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you can use XSLT 2.0 then either of the following would work:

Use the [`string-join()`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_string-join.html) function:

```
<xsl:variable name="companies" select="string-join(catalog/cd/company, ';')" />
```

Use `@separator` with [`xsl:value-of`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#value-of):

```
<xsl:variable name="companies" >
   <xsl:value-of select="catalog/cd/company" separator=";" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: I wish i could use XSLT 2.0. I'm upvoting anyway

Answer (score 4):

**Here is one simple, true XSLT solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="company">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="following::company">;</xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

**the wanted, correct result (all companies concatenated together and delimited by a `;`) is produced**:

```
CBS Records;RCA;Virgin records
```